# Bit Fields access in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

I am trying to access bit fields:

Below is the code which works fine and gives expected result but throws compiler warnings which I have mentioned below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


struct status_type_one{
unsigned delta_cts : 1;// lsb
unsigned delta_dsr : 1;
unsigned tr_edge : 1 ;
unsigned delta_rec : 1;
unsigned cts : 1;
unsigned dsr : 1;
unsigned ring : 1;
unsigned rec_line : 1;// msb
} status_one;

struct status_type_two {
unsigned : 4; // lsb 4 bits
unsigned cts : 1; //bit 5
unsigned dsr : 1; // bit 6
} status_two;



int main(void)
{
  status_one.delta_cts=1;
  status_one.delta_dsr=0;
  status_one.tr_edge=1;
  status_one.delta_rec=0;
  status_one.cts=1;
  status_one.dsr=0;
  status_one.ring=1;
  status_one.rec_line=1;

  printf("The value of status_one is %x\n",status_one);  // warning here

  status_two.cts=1;
  status_two.dsr=1;

  printf("The value of status_one is %d\n",status_two);  // warning here



    return 0;
    }
```

But I am getting below warning:

```
$ gcc -Wall Bit_Fields.c -o Bit_Fields
Bit_Fields.c: In function `main':
Bit_Fields.c:35: warning: unsigned int format, status_type_one arg (arg 2)
Bit_Fields.c:35: warning: unsigned int format, status_type_one arg (arg 2)
Bit_Fields.c:40: warning: int format, status_type_two arg (arg 2)
Bit_Fields.c:40: warning: int format, status_type_two arg (arg 2)
```

The Output is correct as shown below

```
$ ./Bit_Fields
The value of status_one is d5
The value of status_one is 48
```

Can anyone please tell, What the warning is about and how to resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you highlight the two lines.

Comment: `%u` instead of `%d and %x` and use typecase to unsigned

Comment: `%d` expects an int`, not a `struct status_type_one`...

Comment: `printf` doesn't do structs, you have to print fields matching the format specifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to solve this is to have an integer-type union value, e.g:

```
union status_type_one
{
   struct status_type_one{
       unsigned delta_cts : 1;// lsb
       unsigned delta_dsr : 1;
       unsigned tr_edge : 1 ;
       unsigned delta_rec : 1;
       unsigned cts : 1;
       unsigned dsr : 1;
       unsigned ring : 1;
       unsigned rec_line : 1;// msb
   } bits;
   unsigned whole[1];       // Size should match the total bits size.
} status_one;
```

Now, your other code would have to change:

```
status_one.bits.delta_cts=1;
status_one.bits.delta_dsr=0;
status_one.bits.tr_edge=1;
... etc ...
```

and the print:

```
printf("The value of status_one is %x\n",status_one.whole[0]);
```

[Obviously, if the struct is more than one item in whole, you need to either loop or pass several values to printf]

What you are doing may well appear to work, but you are not really supposed to pass a STRUCT to a printf function, and there's no telling what that does if you use more than one machine word worth of data, or what happens on a 64-bit machine, etc, etc.

Comment: why array `whole[1]` , you can use just `whole`, **?**

Comment: Because that won't explain in the same section how to deal with structs that are larger than one <integer type>. If they always are less than 32-bit, then by all means use no array - but the compiler should optimise that away anyways as long as it's a constant.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, could you use `whole[]`?

Comment: Just one mention: Struct and union namae can not be same.. it is throwing error

Comment: @MatsPetersson Can u please explain use of whole[1] a bit more in detail.. I got some idea but not absolutely clear what you mean by that statement.. thanks

Comment: The idea with using an array is that if you have more than one int's worth of data in your bitfields, you can just increase the [1] to [2], [3], [109] or whatever is right for the bitfields you have got. I've worked on projects where we had bitfields up to, I think 2048 bits [in several different portioins of course, as one bitfield isn't allowed to be larger than the integer type used to declare the field]